# Boost installation: missing argument global-setup

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, b2

I am trying to install boost library on Windows 10. I have VS2017 installed. 
I open the Developer Command Prompt 2017, and I already typed `boostrap` and now while writing `b2`, I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_60_0>b2
C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_60_0/tools/build/src/tools\msvc.jam:1072: in configure-really
*** argument error
* rule generate-setup-cmd ( version : command : parent : options * : cpu : global-setup : default-global-setup-options : default-setup )
* called with: ( default : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\Hostx86\x86 : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\Hostx86 :  : i386 :  : x86 : vcvars32.bat )
* missing argument global-setup
C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_60_0/tools/build/src/tools\msvc.jam:798:see definition of rule 'generate-setup-cmd' being called
C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_60_0/tools/build/src/tools\msvc.jam:201: in configure
C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_60_0/tools/build/src/tools\msvc.jam:153: in msvc.init
C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_60_0/tools/build/src/build\toolset.jam:43: in toolset.using
C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_60_0/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:1052: in using
project-config.jam:3: in modules.load
C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_60_0/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:249: in load-config
C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_60_0/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:412: in load-configuration-files
C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_60_0/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:524: in load
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_60_0\tools\build\src/kernel\modules.jam:295: in import
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_60_0\tools\build\src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_60_0\boost-build.jam:17: in module scope
```

I am not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 14):

After running bootstrap edit `project-config.jam` and make changes as shown below.

```
import option ; 

using msvc : 14.0 : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe";
option.set keep-going : false ;
```

Have taken version 14.14.26428 based on the error information you have posted. Make sure that version exist, if not change the version or install the one which is required. 
The above command is for building 32 bit. If you need 64 bit change it to `Hostx64\x64`

Comment: Sorry if this question seems too silly. Where does the `14.0` following `msvc` come from? (I got `Unknown compiler version` message after running `./b2`